# Token refresh fails with invalid_client error

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a refresh token issued by app A. This refresh token is stored in an Azure Key Vault, to which app B has access. App B now takes this refreh token and exchanges it for an access token.

Unfortunately this exchange fails with the message

```
"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": "AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided."
```

The client secret is correct though. I was able to acquire an access token to the Key Vault with it.

This is the HTTP request for the refresh token exchange taken from Fiddler (I have removed all secrets and ids):

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US)  WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.134
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Length: 1221
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=refresh_token
&client_id={ClientId}
&client_secret={ClientSecret}
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F
&refresh_token={RefreshToken}
```

What is going here?

PS: I know it's wild storing a refresh token in a Key Vault, but that's Microsofts recommended way of accessing the CSP Partner API.

Comment: I see that you're specifying `resource=https://vault.azure.net` in the request taken from Fiddler.. shouldn't it be App A or the app for which you want to get access token in exchange for refresh token?

Comment: Good point, thanks! I've changed the resource to https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com now, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as the Rohit said, the resource should be the app that you want to access.
For the details about this, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens).

Comment: Thanks you, I changed the resource to https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com now, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Oh, and to be explicit: I'm using the credentials of App B to exchange to refresh token. Is that the issue? The example in the documentation you linked uses the same app the created the refresh token to exchange it.

Comment: You could try the refresh_token to exchange the access_token for the resource  https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. I had the resource wrong in the OP, fixed it now, but I still get the same error.

Comment: You should use the same client_secret that used to request the refresh_token.